# Docker for Mac cannot access containers outside of host

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` to build and run our application locally. This all works fine but I cannot access the apache container from outside of the host. It will eventually timeout with "server stopped responding".

The docker documentation is terrible and despite my best efforts "docker for mac" is just too generic for Google to understand that it's the name of the product and not a description.

Docker for Mac does not use VirtualBox and I can't find anyone that has managed to get it working, or any information that it's strictly not possible.

I have checked all the obvious stuff:

1. Mac firewall is turned off.
2. The `web` container should not be bound to localhost, `0.0.0.0:1234->80/tcp`.
3. I've port forwarding on the mac with `ssh -L 11234:127.0.0.1:1234 -N 127.0.0.1` but accessing it on `11234` gives me the same error.

What could I try next?

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue, not a docker issue.   What's your netstat show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was our internal wifi network that was blocking the communication between those two devices. So it was working from the start. I am going to close this.

Answer (score 0):

use the -p option when you run it to publish the ports

docker run -p 1234:80 .....

/edit

Also, consider setting up a default docker-machine it tends to make things better on Mac.

/edit again

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

Comment: I am publishing the port, through docker-compose. I am able to access the web container through the published port (localhost:1234) but other devices on the network can't connect.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include how to make a default docker-machine. You can then use normal VirtualBox networking with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `docker-machine`, you can easily display `ip` of `docker-machine` by command:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Then type this `ip` on your browser.